# How to report a user?

Tags: support, users, reporting

A new user with an inappropriate username joined a Stack Exchange site today and started posting overly graphic sex jokes, as answers.

They are clearly just a troll account. How would I go about reporting them for being a troll?

Comment: Simply flag the posts: Flag → Rude or Abusive. Moderators will likely delete the account as well.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that later, they likely got reported by others as well because they are getting a lot of downvotes. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please research how each site works before considering posting a question.

Comment: Such trolls are just part of the place, like criminals are part of life. Unlike criminals IRL they can't do real damage, so no need to freak out, as others said flagging a post is enough, and other methods are explained in the linked duplicate post. Thanks for caring, anyway. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Hates Omicron I wasn't freaking out, don't worry. They were just annoying.

Comment: Also, if they're posting graphical sexual content, you can also report them [in Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq). Even if you don't have [permission to actually report the post](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Commands#privileged-commands), if you post a link to one of those answers with a short description, chances are someone there will report it to SmokeDetector to get it deleted even faster, if it hasn't already been caught.

Answer (score 9):

Flag the post as rude or offensive. In this case you can also do a custom flag letting the mods know the username is offensive + the user is trolling

Comment: "letting the mods know the username is offensive" - I think it's pretty clear without having to tell them, usually. ;)

Comment: We don't see everything with our efficient community flagging 

Comment: Don't you see the name of the author of the post that was flagged in the dashboard??

Comment: Not if the post is nuked before we see it - hence the suggestion of a custom flag, which sticks around, ensuring proper coverage of cleansing fire

Comment: Oh, but I mean you see the name of the post author in the custom flag, so adding there that the name is offensive is usually not needed, unless it's not an obvious offensive name. (Different language, offensive only for certain group etc.) :)

Comment: "LOOK AT THIS" is a terrible flag. "Hey! This person is a troll and a miscreant, and has a naughty name!" Is not.